# Is there an equivalent of rowversion in SQL Server, but for a table?

Tags: sql-server, hash, row, versioning

I am looking for something similar to [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) but for the whole table : a unique number automatically generated that can be used to know if table has changed.

Eg :

```
SELECT TABLE_VERSION('FOO')
0x00000000000007D2

INSERT INTO FOO (...) VALUES (1, 'Hello world')

SELECT TABLE_VERSION('FOO')
0x00000000000007D5
```

Does it exists in SQL Server ?

If not, is there any alternative ? Somethings that allow to track changes on a column would be great too.
I have been thinking of using [HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql), but unfortunately it only gives hash for a single column value not for the whole column.

Comment: Try this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql

Comment: Did you checked "Change Data Capture".

Comment: If you want to use Hashbytes, you can concat all columns in 1 derived column and hash it : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/43c243aa-3eca-4b55-9d74-e976994341ba/unique-row-id-based-on-all-columns-hashbyte-or-checksum?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Maybe getting last update time helps? You can get the last updated date time like:

SELECT last_user_update
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id=DB_ID()
  AND object_id=OBJECT_ID('myTable');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not such a thing in SQL Server, however you can implement it easly with triggers. I have used it to assist cache invalidation for web apps.

first create the table etags:

```
CREATE TABLE etags
(
   etag_name varchar(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   etag_value uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
)
```

Insert a value for the `Foo` table:

```
INSERT INTO etags VALUES ('foo', NEWID())
```

Then create a trigger for the `foo` table that updates the etag value when table changes

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo_etag
ON foo FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  UPDATE etags SET etag_value = NEWID()
  WHERE etag_name = 'Foo'
```

Comment: "I have used it to assist cache invalidation for web apps." That is exactly the reason why I need this.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :-). I usually cache at server and browser side. ETag and If-None-Match headers help on that.